# rails image_submit_tag with cucumber/webrat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, webrat

I've the following search form with image_submit_tag instead of submit_tag.

Now I get the obvious fail when cucumber runs:

```
When I fill in "q" with "sachin"                                               # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:33
And I press "submit"                                                           # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:21
    Could not find button "submit" (Webrat::NotFoundError)
    (eval):2:in `click_button'
    ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:22:in `/^(?:|I )press "([^\"]*)"$/'
    features/search.feature:20:in `And I press "submit"'
```

It fails coz its looking for the submit button.

Since I'm using image_submit_tag, what will be the webrat/cuke step for this tag to make the form submit?

Answer (score 3):

I tried this and it works using the `id` option:

`<%= image_submit_tag "image_file_name", :id => "submit" %>`

and in the feature:

`And I press "submit"`

Note that `:title => "submit"` did not work (even though the Webrat docs says that it checks for both `:id` and `:title`)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will work or not, but try adding a `title` attribute to your image button:

```
image_submit_tag ..., :title => "submit"
```

Comment: or something like :id => "submit_button" if you want an id instead

Comment: Well, I tried both adding :id and :title, it still doesn't work.
So I've removed it and went with the standard <button> element.
Thanks for the comments.

Comment: It was worth a try.  FWIW I've used cuke with image links and had to use a `title` attribute.  What markup does the image_submit_tag generate?